# Bootstrap 3 : Content in a new row is not aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to display content horizontally, but the result is not as expected.

The fifth column ("content 5") should appear on the bottom left, and be aligned with the content above.

[JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/tunuhimuyi)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="fr"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<h3>Content 1</h3>
<h4><a href="#">test</a></h4>
<p>test</p>
<p><span class="my-title">0,00&nbsp;€</span></p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<h3>Content 2</h3>
<h4><a href="#">test</a></h4>
<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
<p><span class="my-title">638,25&nbsp;€</span></p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<h3>Content 3</h3>
<h4><a href="#">tablo</a></h4>
<p>tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo </p>
<p><span class="my-title">555,00&nbsp;€</span></p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<h3>Content 4</h3>
<h4><a href="#">stage castagnettes avec toto</a></h4>
<p>stage castagnettes avec toto</p>
<p><span class="my-title">57,50&nbsp;€</span></p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<h3>Content 5</h3>
<h4><a href="#">reservation trop cool</a></h4>
<p>reservation trop cool</p>
<p><span class="my-title">50,00&nbsp;€</span></p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap the sum of  the `.col`s per `.row` can't be more than 12 (using default grid in bootstrap), and you are having 5 cols with `.col-md-3`, so that's 3x5=15 which is higher than 12(the max grid bootstrap allows by default)

So you have to add another `.row`  for the 5th one.

See more info about grid on [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

**Note** you don't need nested `.row`s in your case.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <h3>Content 1</h3>
      <h4><a href="#">test</a></h4>
      <p>test</p>
      <p><span class="my-title">0,00&nbsp;€</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>Content 2</h3>
      <h4><a href="#">test</a></h4>
      <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </p>
      <p><span class="my-title">638,25&nbsp;€</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>Content 3</h3>
      <h4><a href="#">tablo</a></h4>
      <p>tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo tablo</p>
      <p><span class="my-title">555,00&nbsp;€</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>Content 4</h3>
      <h4><a href="#">stage castagnettes avec toto</a></h4>
      <p>stage castagnettes avec toto</p>
      <p><span class="my-title">57,50&nbsp;€</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>Content 5</h3>
      <h4><a href="#">reservation trop cool</a></h4>
      <p>reservation trop cool</p>
      <p><span class="my-title">50,00&nbsp;€</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```